# How can I make a hybrid bash/tcsh script on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcsh

I have one script which runs in Bash and and other which runs in tcsh.

I need to run them both from the same script. How can I create a script that
can run both bash and tcsh commands?

Comment: `csh` is very different from `bash`. You can consider portability with `sh`-derived shells instead, but not with `tcsh`. It's -very- difficult to keep compatibility with `*csh` an `*sh`.

Comment: `One of my programs only runs in Bash and the other only runs in tcsh` "Please explain..."

Comment: `bash prog1 & csh prog2 &`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most shells have an argument which allow you to pass them a string to run as a command, for example, for bash you can run

```
bash -c "echo this is a bash script; echo lalalala"
```

to run that string as a script in bash, use this to run the needed shell embedded in the other. This will allow you to make a script in one shell which will invoke the other shell when the other program needs to be run.

If on the other hand they are both properly shebanged begin with `#!tcsh` or `#!bash` you can simply run both scripts from the same bash script using:

```
/path/to/script1 &
/path/to/script2 &
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to linux so can you please help me out?

In this picture:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10566383_889632401051040_860617194_n.jpg?oh=d936481ece1d76a38277cd4f87170e75&oe=53CB6ABB&__gda__=1405848036_b2e8cf6a9527130ff867cc9c55a3b101


In the top of the page, you see the bash shell. If I run whatever I have typed in (without the &), everything would run perfectly. Note the directory on the left side. Now, I also want to run the "run.sh" program in that bottom directory (the mesh_bandwidth... one). Could you please tell me what I should run? Thanks

Comment: Ah, it sounds like what you are looking for is to run the script by absolute path, if you write your command as: `parsecmgmt -a run -p blackscholes & ; /home/linaro/--removedLongPath--/run.sh` it should do what you want, note I have not written out the full path (takes me too long to copy the path out of the photo) but you will need to, basically you can run any script by typing the full path to run it from anywhere instead of having to be in the same folder. Is that what you need? If that is what you want I can edit it into the answer.

Comment: I got this error:

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10559133_889648687716078_825646100_n.jpg?oh=03f53f99a6bea5a49fe61ca6320803f7&oe=53CB9CF2&__gda__=1405836015_283c4869747849ccd67d87152e2461ce

Any idea of what I did wrong?

Comment: @user3853033 Try without the ; or failing that put a newline after the &. To expand a little ; means effectively "end of command" and & means "run preceding command in background (without blocking)", however & may imply a ; making the ; wrong, sorry.

Comment: @user3853033 By the way, in future you may have more luck on the unix and Linux stack exchange, it is there specifically for this kind of issue: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think that there's still the problem with the bash vs tcsh shells. The emesh bandwidth stuff would only workin tcsh while the parsec blackscholes would only work in bash. I am doing everything in bash right now. This is the error if you wanted to know, but I'm pretty sure that its because of the bash vs tcsh stuff.

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10559051_889654834382130_1946303589_n.jpg?oh=0cc1d8e959c7a144730e4eb6f563a504&oe=53CB9EA7&__gda__=1405833847_1618ab5e3d8a75884714570952c7f586

Anyway thanks for the help. I'm not sure bout this bash vs tchs problem

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll definately use that. I'm pretty new with Linux so I wasn't sure of where to go for help.

Comment: It does not look to me like a shell problem looking at that error, it seems rather that your program requires the program `mesh_one.elf` to be in the current directory when you run the command. However if you really want to try you can force a command to run inside tcsh by running `tcsh -c "command"` so whichever command you think needs to be in tcsh just wrap it in that.

Comment: The mesh_one.elf file comes after building. This is the error now.

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10559249_889661547714792_717995849_n.jpg?oh=9a93d4206babe438450f17198ade2ab9&oe=53CB4A50&__gda__=1405830925_5c65948fa427edb0a811bb31fba050c6

I know that this is probably getting confusing for you. It's fine. I 'll see if I can manage from here. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @user3853033 I just realized, I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you meant you needed the two commands to run at the same time, try replacing the & with a ; and see if that works. I apologize. Failing that I would flag this question to a moderator to see if you can get it migrated to unix SE.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10559088_889665201047760_1241801873_n.jpg?oh=3b25d4d9b06d0dd9dfa07d92e55e3f9f&oe=53CB8186&__gda__=1405825238_3e0fe7be30ca63709fec8732f140fde8

And yes, I want them to run at the same time, but unforunately, I need to "build" one of them first which doesnt work if I build it through the bash shell. It only works through the tcsh shell

Comment: @user3853033 Nearly, just as I said, replace the `&` between the two commands with a `;` other than that it should be correct.

Comment: It still gives me the gcc: error: src/mesh_one.c: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3853033 I just realised, the second script needs to be run from within it's own directory, inside the quotes after tcsh before you run the run.sh add a `cd /home/linaro/--removedLongPath--/` where the long path is the directory with run.sh in it.

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10537823_889738624373751_481926310_n.jpg?oh=649bf8fe91a318ffbfe5a43ad92628b4&oe=53CB29C3&__gda__=1405828572_81049a7a53ec305a6f5df57c0c5d049b

Is that what you mean? Really confused about why it still says no file or directory

Comment: @user3853033 Sorry for the delay, I had to travel. However, that is nearly there, but the cd should be a separate command. So in full, in the quotes should be `"cd /home/linaro/Parallella/epiphany-examples/mesh_bandwidth_all2one ; ./run.sh"`

Comment: That worked....thanks a bunch for that. Are these programs running simultaneously?

Comment: @user3853033 That depends on if you used the & or the ; as a command separator. The semicolon will run them one after the other and the ampersand will run them at once. I hope that all helped :) If this fixed your issue please consider accepting my answer using the tick by it. Or if there are any more problems just leave another comment.

Comment: Which ampersand/semicolon are you talking about? The one in the middle or the ond\e at the end? Would this be simultaneous or one after another?

parsecmgmt -a run -i simlarge -p streamcluster & tcsh -c "cd /home/linaro/Parallella/epiphany-examples/mesh_bandwidth_bisection ; ./run.sh"

Comment: @user3853033 That command you have there is simultaneous. Specifically, it runs parsecmgmt as a background process and run.sh as a foreground process. And background and foreground threads can run at the same time so will be simutaneous, the only difference is that any control signals such as `ctrl-c` will be sent to the foreground process. & effects whichever command it is directly at the end of.